# How to add a key value pair to a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting

I have 2 single arrays that I want to be added in a multidimensional array but only one at a time. Meaning that array 1 gets added first then array 2 gets added second but they both can't exist in the same array inside the associative array. Let me show you.

```
$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash']
$array2 = ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor']

$AssociativeArray =   array (
    'JobNumber' => '2',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '10',
    'fname' => 'RICARDO',
    'lname' => 'SMITH',
    'RAddress' => 'SUGARAPPLE ST',
    'HomePhone' => '3924651',
    'WorkPhone' => '3276200',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FROM POLICE STATION, EAST INTO PINEWOOD..3RD LFT ONTO SUGARAPPLE ST;  5TH HSE ON RGT; BEIGE/YELLW #19',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '010106',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10221401',
    'offernum' => '2136370',

  ),
  122 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '30',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '213',
    'fname' => 'MONIQUE',
    'lname' => 'SAWYER NAIRN',
    'RAddress' => 'SUTTON ST',
    'HomePhone' => '8017750',
    'WorkPhone' => '2250417',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'TRN ONTO KEMP RD FRM SHIRLEY ST,   1ST LFT BY LODGE BLDG, 2ND RT,     UNPAINTED HSE AT DEAD END. #13     ...SDW',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '213308',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '11390602',
    'offernum' => '2137494',

  ),
  176 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '22',
    'JobType' => '1',
    'Node' => '128',
    'fname' => 'OSMANY',
    'lname' => 'GODEICH',
    'RAddress' => 'HUDSON STREET',
    'HomePhone' => '8148003',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'VILLAGE RD ONTO ST ANDREWS DR      LFT @ TJUN, 3RD RGT TO 4 WAY JUNT  BLDG ON LFT WHIT/GRN 4PLEX         UNIT#2. lim',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '128101',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10036246',
    'offernum' => '2137124',
  ),
  235 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '5',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '27',
    'fname' => 'ROSALIE',
    'lname' => 'BAIN',
    'RAddress' => 'NASSAU VILLAGE',
    'HomePhone' => '4233021',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FRM SOLDIER RD TO NASSAU VILLAGE;MKRGT AT T-JUNC;7TH LFT OPP BUDGET,  2ND BUILDING ON THE RIGHT (S&M)    BEIGE/GREEN APT #1 4233021         call b4 arrive',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '027401',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '12621206',
    'offernum' => '2136937',
  ),
)%
```

So essentially I will want my output to look like this:

```
array (
    'JobNumber' => '2',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '10',
    'fname' => 'RICARDO',
    'lname' => 'SMITH',
    'RAddress' => 'SUGARAPPLE ST',
    'HomePhone' => '3924651',
    'WorkPhone' => '3276200',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FROM POLICE STATION, EAST INTO PINEWOOD..3RD LFT ONTO SUGARAPPLE ST;  5TH HSE ON RGT; BEIGE/YELLW #19',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '010106',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10221401',
    'offernum' => '2136370',
    'installer1' => 'Aaron Cash',
  ),
  122 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '30',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '213',
    'fname' => 'MONIQUE',
    'lname' => 'SAWYER NAIRN',
    'RAddress' => 'SUTTON ST',
    'HomePhone' => '8017750',
    'WorkPhone' => '2250417',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'TRN ONTO KEMP RD FRM SHIRLEY ST,   1ST LFT BY LODGE BLDG, 2ND RT,     UNPAINTED HSE AT DEAD END. #13     ...SDW',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '213308',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '11390602',
    'offernum' => '2137494',
    'installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor',
  ),
  176 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '22',
    'JobType' => '1',
    'Node' => '128',
    'fname' => 'OSMANY',
    'lname' => 'GODEICH',
    'RAddress' => 'HUDSON STREET',
    'HomePhone' => '8148003',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'VILLAGE RD ONTO ST ANDREWS DR      LFT @ TJUN, 3RD RGT TO 4 WAY JUNT  BLDG ON LFT WHIT/GRN 4PLEX         UNIT#2. lim',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '128101',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10036246',
    'offernum' => '2137124',
    'installer1' => 'Aaron Cash',
  ),
  235 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '5',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '27',
    'fname' => 'ROSALIE',
    'lname' => 'BAIN',
    'RAddress' => 'NASSAU VILLAGE',
    'HomePhone' => '4233021',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FRM SOLDIER RD TO NASSAU VILLAGE;MKRGT AT T-JUNC;7TH LFT OPP BUDGET,  2ND BUILDING ON THE RIGHT (S&M)    BEIGE/GREEN APT #1 4233021         call b4 arrive',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '027401',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '12621206',
    'offernum' => '2136937',
    'installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor',
  ),
)%
```

Is there anyway to do this? I am basically trying to assign technicians to a job but I need to figure out a way to assign techs an equal amount of jobs.

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: do you want to all the elements in `$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash']` will be added to the first element of `$AssociativeArray` and run the loop in a similar way for the next second array to next element of the associative array ?

Comment: yes this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to solve this for you it's very simple you just needed to loop through the associative array and then add the elements from the other arrays alternatively.

[here](https://tehplayground.com/tp9d3hRAkvaYeuYo) is the working example of the code.

```
<?php

$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash'];
$array2 = ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor'];

$AssociativeArray =   [
    array (
        'JobNumber' => '2',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '10',
        'fname' => 'RICARDO',
        'lname' => 'SMITH',
        'RAddress' => 'SUGARAPPLE ST',
        'HomePhone' => '3924651',
        'WorkPhone' => '3276200',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'FROM POLICE STATION, EAST INTO PINEWOOD..3RD LFT ONTO SUGARAPPLE ST;  5TH HSE ON RGT; BEIGE/YELLW #19',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '010106',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '10221401',
        'offernum' => '2136370',
    ),
    array (
        'JobNumber' => '30',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '213',
        'fname' => 'MONIQUE',
        'lname' => 'SAWYER NAIRN',
        'RAddress' => 'SUTTON ST',
        'HomePhone' => '8017750',
        'WorkPhone' => '2250417',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'TRN ONTO KEMP RD FRM SHIRLEY ST,   1ST LFT BY LODGE BLDG, 2ND RT,     UNPAINTED HSE AT DEAD END. #13     ...SDW',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '213308',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '11390602',
        'offernum' => '2137494',
        'installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor',
    ),
    array (
        'JobNumber' => '22',
        'JobType' => '1',
        'Node' => '128',
        'fname' => 'OSMANY',
        'lname' => 'GODEICH',
        'RAddress' => 'HUDSON STREET',
        'HomePhone' => '8148003',
        'WorkPhone' => '',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'VILLAGE RD ONTO ST ANDREWS DR      LFT @ TJUN, 3RD RGT TO 4 WAY JUNT  BLDG ON LFT WHIT/GRN 4PLEX         UNIT#2. lim',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '128101',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '10036246',
        'offernum' => '2137124',
        'installer1' => 'Aaron Cash',
    ),
    array (
        'JobNumber' => '5',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '27',
        'fname' => 'ROSALIE',
        'lname' => 'BAIN',
        'RAddress' => 'NASSAU VILLAGE',
        'HomePhone' => '4233021',
        'WorkPhone' => '',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'FRM SOLDIER RD TO NASSAU VILLAGE;MKRGT AT T-JUNC;7TH LFT OPP BUDGET,  2ND BUILDING ON THE RIGHT (S&M)    BEIGE/GREEN APT #1 4233021         call b4 arrive',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '027401',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '12621206',
        'offernum' => '2136937',
        'installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor',
    ),
];

$i=0;
foreach($AssociativeArray as $key => $arr){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        foreach($array1 as $key1 => $val1){
            $AssociativeArray[$key][$key1] = $val1;
        }
    }else{
        foreach($array2 as $key2 => $val2){
            $AssociativeArray[$key][$key2] = $val2;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($AssociativeArray);
```

To add a third array into the above solution you need to modify the code as following.

```
$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash'];
$array2 = ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor'];
$array3 = ['installer3' => 'Omar Abbas'];

$tempArr = [$array1,$array2,$array3];

$i=-1;
foreach($AssociativeArray as $key => $arr){
    $i = ($i < 2 ? $i+1 : 0);
    foreach($tempArr[$i] as $key1 => $val1){
        $AssociativeArray[$key][$key1] = $val1;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want to add a third array in the mix how do it add that as well? Basically using 3 installers instead of 2

Comment: @KeithRoye please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```php
<?php

$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash'];
$array2 = ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor'];

$AssociativeArray = array(
    array(
        'JobNumber' => '2',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '10',
        'fname' => 'RICARDO',
        'lname' => 'SMITH',
        'RAddress' => 'SUGARAPPLE ST',
        'HomePhone' => '3924651',
        'WorkPhone' => '3276200',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'FROM POLICE STATION, EAST INTO PINEWOOD..3RD LFT ONTO SUGARAPPLE ST;  5TH HSE ON RGT; BEIGE/YELLW #19',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '010106',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '10221401',
        'offernum' => '2136370',

    ),
    122 =>
    array(
        'JobNumber' => '30',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '213',
        'fname' => 'MONIQUE',
        'lname' => 'SAWYER NAIRN',
        'RAddress' => 'SUTTON ST',
        'HomePhone' => '8017750',
        'WorkPhone' => '2250417',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'TRN ONTO KEMP RD FRM SHIRLEY ST,   1ST LFT BY LODGE BLDG, 2ND RT,     UNPAINTED HSE AT DEAD END. #13     ...SDW',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '213308',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '11390602',
        'offernum' => '2137494',

    ),
    176 =>
    array(
        'JobNumber' => '22',
        'JobType' => '1',
        'Node' => '128',
        'fname' => 'OSMANY',
        'lname' => 'GODEICH',
        'RAddress' => 'HUDSON STREET',
        'HomePhone' => '8148003',
        'WorkPhone' => '',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'VILLAGE RD ONTO ST ANDREWS DR      LFT @ TJUN, 3RD RGT TO 4 WAY JUNT  BLDG ON LFT WHIT/GRN 4PLEX         UNIT#2. lim',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '128101',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '10036246',
        'offernum' => '2137124',
    ),
    235 =>
    array(
        'JobNumber' => '5',
        'JobType' => '3',
        'Node' => '27',
        'fname' => 'ROSALIE',
        'lname' => 'BAIN',
        'RAddress' => 'NASSAU VILLAGE',
        'HomePhone' => '4233021',
        'WorkPhone' => '',
        'RTime' => '10-12',
        'Comment' => 'FRM SOLDIER RD TO NASSAU VILLAGE;MKRGT AT T-JUNC;7TH LFT OPP BUDGET,  2ND BUILDING ON THE RIGHT (S&M)    BEIGE/GREEN APT #1 4233021         call b4 arrive',
        'FTax' => '1.00',
        'Tag' => '027401',
        'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
        'Cust_Acct' => '12621206',
        'offernum' => '2136937',
    )
);

// Generate the final array
$result = [];
$installerIndex = 0;

foreach ($AssociativeArray as $key => $value) {
    $installerIndex++; //Increase the operator index
    $operatorArray = ($installerIndex % 2) ? $array1 : $array2;  // Select the operator array using the current index
    $result[$key] = $value + $operatorArray; // Merge the value with the selected operator info
}

}
```

But I would put the two installer together in an associative array, something like this:

```
$installerArray = [
    ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash'],
    ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor']
];
```

This way you could access them more easily, and the loop would look like this:

```php
foreach ($AssociativeArray as $key => $value) {
    $operatorIndex++; //Increase the operator index
    $result[$key] = $value + $installerArray[$operatorIndex%2]; // Merge the value with the selected operator info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for code 
correction on first line for multidimensional array

```
$AssociativeArray =   array (
    array(
```

and in last line use of array_push function to add both arrays in AssociativeArray

```
$array1 = ['installer1' => 'Aaron Cash'];
$array2 = ['installer2' => 'Wayne Taylor'];

$AssociativeArray =   array (
array(
    'JobNumber' => '2',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '10',
    'fname' => 'RICARDO',
    'lname' => 'SMITH',
    'RAddress' => 'SUGARAPPLE ST',
    'HomePhone' => '3924651',
    'WorkPhone' => '3276200',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FROM POLICE STATION, EAST INTO PINEWOOD..3RD LFT ONTO SUGARAPPLE ST;  5TH HSE ON RGT; BEIGE/YELLW #19',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '010106',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10221401',
    'offernum' => '2136370',

  ),
  122 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '30',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '213',
    'fname' => 'MONIQUE',
    'lname' => 'SAWYER NAIRN',
    'RAddress' => 'SUTTON ST',
    'HomePhone' => '8017750',
    'WorkPhone' => '2250417',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'TRN ONTO KEMP RD FRM SHIRLEY ST,   1ST LFT BY LODGE BLDG, 2ND RT,     UNPAINTED HSE AT DEAD END. #13     ...SDW',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '213308',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '11390602',
    'offernum' => '2137494',

  ),
  176 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '22',
    'JobType' => '1',
    'Node' => '128',
    'fname' => 'OSMANY',
    'lname' => 'GODEICH',
    'RAddress' => 'HUDSON STREET',
    'HomePhone' => '8148003',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'VILLAGE RD ONTO ST ANDREWS DR      LFT @ TJUN, 3RD RGT TO 4 WAY JUNT  BLDG ON LFT WHIT/GRN 4PLEX         UNIT#2. lim',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '128101',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '10036246',
    'offernum' => '2137124',
  ),
  235 =>
  array (
    'JobNumber' => '5',
    'JobType' => '3',
    'Node' => '27',
    'fname' => 'ROSALIE',
    'lname' => 'BAIN',
    'RAddress' => 'NASSAU VILLAGE',
    'HomePhone' => '4233021',
    'WorkPhone' => '',
    'RTime' => '10-12',
    'Comment' => 'FRM SOLDIER RD TO NASSAU VILLAGE;MKRGT AT T-JUNC;7TH LFT OPP BUDGET,  2ND BUILDING ON THE RIGHT (S&M)    BEIGE/GREEN APT #1 4233021         call b4 arrive',
    'FTax' => '1.00',
    'Tag' => '027401',
    'QuotaGroup' => '1.00',
    'Cust_Acct' => '12621206',
    'offernum' => '2136937',
  ),
);
array_push($AssociativeArray, $array1,$array2);
```